# styled-components causing unexpected behaviour when rendering props

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a WhiteBox react component which simply renders a white box with some styles. 
I have a SmallBox react component which simply uses WhiteBox to render a more specific box.
I have a Content react component which renders three SmallBox boxes which does what it's supposed to do (renders three white boxes).
However when I tried to add a text as a props from the parent, the white box is aligned with some unexpected margin from top.
NOTE: when I simply put "This is a text" the css is okay, but when I send "this is a text" as props.text, the whitebox is rendered with extra margin from top.
I Use styled-components and react as I said.

I've tried to console.log the text, and everything seems to be okay. I also tried to switch the props.children or props.text and it does not work

-----------------White Box Component ----------------------

````
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledBox = styled.div`
  display: inline-block;
  width: ${props => props.width}px;
  height: ${props => props.height}px;
  margin-right: ${props => props.marginRight}px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;

  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #646777;
  padding: 10px;
`;
const WhiteBox = props => {
  return (
    <StyledBox
      width={props.width}
      height={props.height}
      marginRight={props.marginRight}
    >
      {props.text} // if I change this to simply "this is a text" it works well. somehow the props.text is causing problems.
    </StyledBox>
  );
};

export default WhiteBox;```

-----------------Small Box Component ----------------------

import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import WhiteBox from "../whitebox/white-box";

const SmallBox = props => {
  return (
    <WhiteBox width={320} height={130} marginRight={70} marginLeft={70} text={props.text}>
    </WhiteBox>
  );
};

export default SmallBox;


-----------------Content Component ----------------------


import React, { Component } from "react";
import SmallBox from "./smallbox/small-box";

import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledContent = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  left: 320px;
  top: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f3f7;
`;


class Content extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <StyledContent>
          <SmallBox text="this text is great" /> // causing problem
          <SmallBox />
          <SmallBox />
        </StyledContent>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Content;
````

Comment: can't reproduce the problem. your code works as you want. your StyledContent has a size of 100% but a top and left offset though. maybe that's causing your problem on reload? why the 3 ticks in export default WhiteBox;``` ?

Comment: the three ticks? only here in the SOF question, not in my code. it is hard to explain without a picture, but anyway, somehow when I add text to the white box and to only 1 or 2 out of 3 boxes, the css is going nuts. only when all three SmallBox are texted, the boxes appear on top without margin as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has to do with how many lines are rendered. The longer the text in the props, the more the lines rendered.

One solution would be to change the `display` property for WhiteBox:

```
const StyledBox = styled.div`
  display: inline-flex;
  ....
`;
```

Another solution would be to override the default style `vertical-align: baseline`, simply add `vertical-align: top;`

```
const StyledBox = styled.div`
  display: inline-block;
  ....
  vertical-align: top;
`;
```